# Link won't work on ajax environment

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have created my ajax.php but the problem is the links i have given won't work. Here are my codes.

```
    // Insert a new row in the table for each person returned
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $student_id = $row['student_id']; 
    $searchResults .= "<tr>\n";
    $searchResults .= "  <td>{$row['LRN']}</td>\n";
    $searchResults .= "  <td>{$row['first_name']}</td>\n";
    $searchResults .= "  <td>{$row['last_name']}</td>\n";
    $searchResults .= "  <td>{$row['grade']}</td>\n";
    $searchResults .= "  <td>{$row['section']}</td>\n";
    $searchResults .= "  <td><a href='Student_View.php?id={$student_id}'>View</a> </td>\n";
    $searchResults .= "  <td><a href='Admin_Edit_Student_Info.php?id={$student_id}'>Update</a></td>\n";
    $searchResults .= "  <td><a href='Admin_Delete_Student.php?id={$student_id}' onclick=\"if (! confirm('Delete this student?')) return false;\">Delete</a></td>\n";
    $searchResults .= "</tr>\n";
}
}
?>
```

I am referring to link

```
<a href='Admin_Edit_Student_Info.php?id={$student_id}'>View</a>
<a href='Admin_Edit_Student_Info.php?id={$student_id}'>Update</a> and
<a href='Admin_Delete_Student.php?id={$student_id}' onclick=\"if (! confirm('Delete this student?')) return false;\">Delete</a>
```

I've been trying to figuring this our for about a week declaring the id={$student_id}' but maybe i was wrong on the right place of declaring it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This !

```
<a href='Admin_Edit_Student_Info.php?id=<?php echo $student_id;  ?>'>Send</a>
```

Comment: I tried it already but have the same affect on my previous code.

Comment: How about this .. $searchResults .= "  <td><a href='Student_View.php?id=".$student_id."'>View</a> </td>\n";

Answer (score 0):

You can also do like this:

```
$searchResults .= "<td><a href='Admin_Delete_Student.php?id=".$student_id."' onclick=\"if (! confirm('Delete this student?')) return false;\">Delete</a></td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

How about changing youre code like this ..

```
$student_id = $row['student_id'];
$searchResults .= "<tr>\n";
$searchResults .= "  <td>".$row['LRN']."</td>\n";
$searchResults .= "  <td>".$row['first_name']."</td>\n";
$searchResults .= "  <td>".$row['last_name']."</td>\n";
$searchResults .= "  <td>".$row['grade']."</td>\n";
$searchResults .= "  <td>".$row['section']."</td>\n";
$searchResults .= "  <td><a href='Student_View.php?id=".$student_id."'>View</a> </td>\n";
$searchResults .= "  <td><a href='Admin_Edit_Student_Info.php?id=".$student_id."'>Update</a>               </td>\n";
$searchResults .= "  <td><a href='Admin_Delete_Student.php?id=".$student_id."' onclick=\"if (!         confirm('Delete this student?')) return false;\">Delete</a></td>\n";
$searchResults .= "</tr>\n";
```

Comment: i tried your suggested codes and it went great in both chrome and mozilla. May i know what are the difference of my previous code to the codes you generated. Thank you very much it save me much time and worries.

Comment: Thanks for the TUT. i'll follow it to learn more. You've been a great help.

Comment: It's my pleasuse :) .